# frozen window during heavy operation

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, progress

im trying to load some files from folders and i want to show the progress of it with progress bar. At this point i tried multiprocessing, timers, threads and nothing is working... I dont know why my code is not working.
after run this code it shows me basic window but after line where i want to compare files, which is heavy operation, but im calling refresh of prograss bar here and in my console i see that it is working but the window with progress bar is frozen the whole time and never refresh :(( (Not responding)

```
#here is box with progress bar
self.ex[0]=showLoadingBox(len(files[1]))
#this is the heavy operation that i want to show the progress
duplsCompare=self.comPictures(files, sett.qualityMeasure)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def comPictures(self,ignSource, prepQ):
    dp = []
    ret = []
    source = ignSource[1]

    for index, item in enumerate(source):
        #here im trying to refresh progress bar
        reload(self.ex[0],index+1)
        for p in source[index + 1:]:
            #do some stuff with files...

    #return comparedFiles
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------reloading method
def reload(self,load):
    if(not(self.count==0)):
        val=int((load/self.count)*100)
    else:
        val=100

    self.pBar.setValue(val)
    print(val)

    if(not(load<self.count)):
        self.close()
```

After end of comparing the window start working but that worthless for me i need that prograss bar show the prograss of comparing.

UPDATE:
so i use threading module but still no progress here literally. Window with progress bar just frozen and show me no progress and not reponding still the same problem even with different thread...

```
    retComPic=[]
    t=Thread(target=self.comPictures,args=(files, sett.qualityMeasure,retComPic))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    while(not(len(retComPic))):
        reload(self.ex[0])

    t.join()
    # self.ex[0].close()
    duplsCompare=retComPic[0]
```

The result is the same percentage right in the console but progress window frozen

Comment: run it on another thread.

Comment: How? I tried that but I did something wrong obviosly :(

Comment: @ZdeněkSklenář. What's stopping you from searching for "[pyqt thread](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyqt+thread+site:stackoverflow.com)"? There are dozens of examples.

Comment: I tried different options as i mentioned before. So thanks for the way... However im trying that examples and app is still not working.

Comment: turns out that signals was neccesary to do this
anybody from you two want be marked as the answer please respond this question correctly and i will mark your answer.